# RecyclerView Adapter performance approach

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I've an AsyncTask that download data from Internet, create less than 30 **MyObject** object, and add it in a list. At the end, I will create a **MyAdapter** passing the list as parameter and set **MyAdapter** as the recycler view adapter:

```
 myList.add(new MyObject("aa", "bb", cc"); //for each piece of data by Internet
 MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(myList);
 recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Now I'm thinking about a better programming way: I create a new **MyAdapter** before of the AsyncTask starts, assign that to the RecyclerView and for each new **MyObject** I call a **MyAdapter** method that add the object in a list and call the **notifyItemInserted**:

```
 myAdapter = new MyAdapter();
 recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
 myAdapter.addMyObject(new MyObject("aa", "bb", cc"); //for each piece of data by Internet

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
     private List<News> data = new ArrayAdapter<>();

     public void addMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
        data.add(myObject);
        notifyItemInserted(this.data.size() -1);
     }
}
```

I would like to understand if the second approach is better than the first one in terms of:

1. Responsive UI;
2. Performance;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but I think that the second approach force your RecyclerView to redraw itself ~ 30 times (one for each of your MyObject), while the first does just one drawing process. Since you have few elements, I think that first approach is ok. But wait for the answer of someone more skilled in this field than me.

Comment: Maybe RecyclerView will not totally redraw itself. With notifyItemInserted, will only draw the new item, isn't it?

Comment: I think that even with notifyItemInserted recycler has, at least, to do some measurement of itself and of the previously inserted items but, as I said, I'm not an expert in the UI field.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach  is better. Recycler view will batch all of the add calls until next animation frame and will only bind new items (if they are visible). It is even better if you can call `notifyItemRangeInserted`. Of course I'm assuming that this AsyncTask runs multiple times, otherwise, it does not matter.

Comment: But I found that with the second approach, an Exception is raised, with the following message: "Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"

Comment: Well that means you are calling it while RecyclerView is in the middle of calculating a layout. The stack trace should be obvious but I'm happy to help if you can share it.